# Cast Any of String to Int

Tags: scala

I have a variable of type `Any` with runtime type of `String` which I want to cast to `Int`:

```
val a: Any = "123"
```

If I try to cast in to Int, I'll get an exception `java.lang.ClassCastException`:

```
val b = a.asInstanceOf[Int]
```

How do I do that then?

Comment: In Java its `Integer.toString`... You should be able to use it from scala as well.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Casting doesn't *convert* your type, it simply tells the system that you think you are smart enough to know the proper type of an object. For example:

```
trait Foo
case class Bar(i: Int) extends Foo

val f: Foo = Bar(33)
val b = f.asInstanceOf[Bar]  // phew, it works, it is indeed a Bar
```

What you are probably looking for is to convert a `String` to an `Int`:

```
val a: Any = "123"
val b = a.asInstanceOf[String].toInt
```

Or, since you can call `toString` on any object:

```
val b = a.toString.toInt
```

You can still get a runtime exception if the string is not a valid number, e.g.

```
"foo".toInt  // boom!
```

Comment: well, `a.asInstanceOf[String].toInt` it's a double casting and I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: `toInt` _is not a casting_. It is a conversion method that basically goes back to `java.lang.Integer.parseInt`

Comment: what's the difference between casting and conversion?

Comment: A cast means you tell the virtual machine that you think you know that a value `x` must be of a given type `A`. After the cast, you can call the interface (methods) of `A` on `x`. It doesn't alter `x` in any way, it only verifies at runtime that it is indeed an `A` (otherwise throwing a `ClassCastException`). A conversion takes a value of type `A` and produces a completely independent new value of type `B`. A conversion is a regular method call checked at compile time.

Comment: which one should I normally use and which one is less expensive (faster)?

Comment: There are only few situations where you need casting, in almost all scenarios you should be able to do without casting. Casting is a good way of shooting yourself in the foot and typically an indicator of bad design. If you have types only known at runtime, prefer pattern matching if possible.

Comment: which one is less expensive (faster)?

Comment: "which one is less expensive (faster)", the question doesn't make sense because it's not about choosing between the two. But if you want to know, both are extremely cheap.

Answer (score 2):

In general you steer clear of class casts and nested `try catch` blocks in Scala.

```
import scala.util.{ Try, Failure, Success };

val x: Any = 5;
val myInt = Try { x.toString.toInt) } getOrElse { 0 // or whatever}; // this is defaulting
val mySecondInt = Try { x.toString.toInt };
mySecondInt match {
   case Success(theactualInt) => // do stuff
   case Failure(e) => // log the exception etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> val a:Any = "123"
a: Any = 123

scala> val b = a.toString.toInt
b: Int = 123
```